# Sencha Touch 2 xtype not working as expected

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

SO I am building my first Sencha Touch App and I am having a problem with rendering a Panel that I have defined.

Login.js

```
Ext.define("Blog.view.Login", {
  extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
  requires : ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.field.Email', 'Ext.field.Password'],
  xtype: 'loginpanel',

  config:{
    scrollable:true,
    title: "Log In",

    items:[
      {
        html:"<center><h1>OkShit</h1></center>",
        styleHtmlContent:true
      },
      {
        xtype:'fieldset',
        items:[
          {
            xtype:'emailfield',
            name:'email',
            placeHolder:'E-Mail'
          },

          {
            xtype:'passwordfield',
            name:'password',
            placeHolder:'Password'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        xtype:'button',
        text:'Log In',
        style:{
          marginBottom:'20px'
        }
      },
      {
        xtype:'button',
        text:'Sign Up'
      }
    ]
  }

});
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define("Blog.view.Main", {
  extend:'Ext.Container',

  config:{
    items:[
      {
        xtype :'loginpanel'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

app.js

```
views: ['Main', 'Login'],
```

I did some research already and someone suggested to use

```
alias: 'widget.loginpanel'
```

I tried it but it still did not work. Does anyone have any solution to this?

**EDIT**
This is what I have right now and it is still not doing anything =(

```
Ext.define("Blog.view.Login", {
  extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.loginpanel',
  requires : ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.field.Email', 'Ext.field.Password'], ...
```

Comment: `alias: 'widget.loginpanel'` works for me, check for spelling and capitalization mistakes, id also place it before requires not that it should matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's not really necessary to use **alias** because you've already defined that class and registered it with a **xtype** in Sencha Touch 2.

Which browser are you using? Please see if there are any errors logged in browser debugger and paste here. I will try to help you out.

Comment: thanks for the reply. there is no error and I am using Chrome for this

Comment: I've modified a little bit your source code and it works fine. Take a look to the two configs, it did the tricks. xD
`Ext.define("Blog.view.Main", {
  extend:'Ext.Container',

  config:{
   fullscreen: true,
   layout: 'card',
    items:[
      {
        xtype :'loginpanel'
      }
    ]
  }
});`

Comment: awesome! i need the layout: 'card'!